# wikipedia scraping plain text and hyperlink with jsoup

Tags: jsoup, screen-scraping, wikipedia

I have a Wikipedia element that looks like this that I want to scrape with Jsoup. I want to take elements into a list of string and separate them when there is 
  if that makes sense. Right now, I am looping Elements in all children of , which misses plain texts like CCCC and GGGG. Is there any way to catch plain texts as well as hyperlinked texts?

```
<td class="" style="" itemprop="">
<a href="/wiki/%E5%9C%8B%E5%AD%B8%E9%99%A2%E5%A4%A7%E5%AD%B8" title="AAAA">AAAA</a> 
<a href="/wiki/%E6%96%87%E5%AD%A6%E9%83%A8" title="BBBB">BBBB</a>
"CCCC"
<br>
"DDDD"
<a href="/wiki/%E5%A4%A7%E5%AD%A6%E9%99%A2" title="EEEE">EEEE</a>
<a href="/wiki/%E6%96%87%E5%AD%A6%E7%A0%94%E7%A9%B6%E7%A7%91" title="FFFF">FFFF</a> 
<br>
GGGG
</td>
```

the Wikipedia page looks like this (bold are hyperlinked texts):

**AAAABBBB**CCCC

DDDD**EEEEFFFF**

GGGG

I want to create a list like this:
[AAAABBBBCCCC, DDDDEEEEFFFF, GGGGG]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this specific case you can do a preprocessing on html to make things easer for Jsoup. Try this code:

```
    String html = "<table><td class=\"\" style=\"\" itemprop=\"\">\n" +
            "<a href=\"/wiki/%E5%9C%8B%E5%AD%B8%E9%99%A2%E5%A4%A7%E5%AD%B8\" title=\"AAAA\">AAAA</a> \n" +
            "<a href=\"/wiki/%E6%96%87%E5%AD%A6%E9%83%A8\" title=\"BBBB\">BBBB</a>\n" +
            "\"CCCC\"\n" +
            "<br>\n" +
            "\"DDDD\"\n" +
            "<a href=\"/wiki/%E5%A4%A7%E5%AD%A6%E9%99%A2\" title=\"EEEE\">EEEE</a>\n" +
            "<a href=\"/wiki/%E6%96%87%E5%AD%A6%E7%A0%94%E7%A9%B6%E7%A7%91\" title=\"FFFF\">FFFF</a> \n" +
            "<br>\n" +
            "GGGG\n" +
            "</td></table>";

    html = html.replace("<br>", "</td><td>");

    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
    List<String> result = doc.select("td").eachText()
            .stream()
            .map(r -> r.replace("\"", ""))
            .map(r -> r.replace(" ", ""))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: I am scraping hundreds of wikipedia pages of this kind, some of them have more than 2 <a>s or only 1 <a> while others have only plain texts and no <br> is there any way to write a scrape all these different patterns?

Comment: can you provide can example of tag structure that does not fit in the example I provided?

Comment: I solved the problem, your eachText() was the solution. Thanks